# How to create a regex that will match an arbitrary sequence of spaces and tabs

Tags: regex

Could anyone help me to assemble a pattern that matches an arbitrary sequence of spaces and tabs?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
[ \t]+
```

will match arbitrary sequences (e.g., spaces followed by tabs followed by more spaces ...).

Comment: In the default regex mode, you'll have to escape the +: [ \t]\+

Comment: @EndreBoth - Why would you want to escape the `+`? It's being used as a quantifier, not trying to match a literal `+` character. Are you talking about a particular language's flavor of regex?

Comment: Thanks @JustinMorgan, I had probably mistaken this for a Vim question. Apologies.

Comment: `[ \t]*` for zero or more spaces/tabs.

Answer (score 57):

`\s+` should capture all whitespace, including spaces, tabs, carriage returns, and some weird whitespace characters. Use `\s*` if you want it to be optional.

Comment: Great answer! Note, this tool is really helpful to verify the meaning of regular expressions: https://regex101.com/.

Answer (score 10):

`( |\t)+` will match a sequence of one or more spaces or tabs, is that what you're looking for ?

Answer (score 7):

To piggy-back on [@Justin Morgan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4972133/4561887), note that according to https://regex101.com/, `\s+` is equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]+`. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/9Ov0Tg/1), and look at the "Explanation" section to the right.

Therefore, if your system doesn't support the `\s+` (or `\s*`) construct, use `[\r\n\t\f\v ]` in place of the `\s` part instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[ \t]*` to match an arbitrary sequence of zero or more space and tabs in any order.

(putting together answer by @mob and comment by @Siva Praveen)