# How to make a regular expression for given kind of String?

Tags: java, regex

How to write the regular expression for below kind of String such that I  get response in below format ?

```
"abc, -xyz, lmn, qwe,-yui"
```

Basically I need to parse above string in `List<String>` as

```
abc, -xyz
lmn
qwe, -yui
```

Below code is working fine when there is exactly one space before hyphen(-) ex:

```
"abc, -xyz"
```

but not working when there is no or more than one space, ex:

```
"abc,  -xyz"
```

Regular expression I tried:

```
List<String> items = Arrays.stream(order.split("(?!, -),")).map(String::trim).map(String::toLowerCase).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Please provide the code which parse with any number of spaces and also explain the logic for the same.

Comment: If you are parsing CSV data it might be easier to use some utility, as opposed to writing regular expressions for it.

Comment: As every `,` you want to split on is preceded by a `"`, split on `",` and re-add the now missing `"` on every element but the last

Comment: As you can see, people start guessing about the nature of the problem you are trying to solve here. Thus: consider telling us *why* you want to split such strings, and where they "come from".

Comment: If your issue is the white space, then you may change your regex to `"(?!,\\s+-),"`

Comment: Use `"(?!,\\s*-),"`

Comment: above code works, thanks a lot.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It would be great if you can explain the code in short. Thanks

Comment: @Toto How can this be a duplicate to what you have marked ? Please explain.

Comment: I added another dupe, your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4972133/3832970). `(?!,\s*-),` matches any comma that is not followed with any 0 or more whitespaces and a `-`. It is equal to `,(?!\s*-)`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting your string you can actually find all results using `"(.+?)"`. This finds all string between `"`. Here is the full example:

```
String input = "\"abc, -xyz\", \"lmn\", \"qwe,-yui\"";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"(?<item>.+?)\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    items.add(matcher.group("item"));
}
items.forEach(System.out::println);
```

The result will be this:

```
abc, -xyz
lmn
qwe,-yui
```

You also can use `.trim(),toLowercase()` before adding an item to the list if you need that.